# Embed Mayavi into a class and show the figure on a Jupyter Notebook cell

Tags: python, jupyter, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I'm trying to integrate Mayavi with my workflow in Jupyter Notebook. The following stripped-down-to-the-bone code example might seems unnecessary complicated, but those are the restrictions I'm not allowed to change.

The class `Test` is used to plot something into an `mlab` figure. The class `Wrapper` instantiates the `Test` class, whereas the `wrapper_func()` function is exposed to the user: it returns the `Wrapper` instance and should display the `mlab` figure when the keyword argument `show=True`.

Note: I'm not allowed to change `Wrapper` and `wrapper_func`. Also, the `Test` class should implement the `show()` method.

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.init_notebook()
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = mlab.figure()
        self._add_data()
        
    def _add_data(self):
        pi = np.pi
        cos = np.cos
        sin = np.sin
        dphi, dtheta = pi / 250.0, pi / 250.0
        [phi, theta] = np.mgrid[0:pi + dphi * 1.5:dphi,
                                0:2 * pi + dtheta * 1.5:dtheta]
        m0 = 4; m1 = 3; m2 = 2; m3 = 3
        m4 = 6; m5 = 2; m6 = 6; m7 = 4
        r = sin(m0 * phi) ** m1 + cos(m2 * phi) ** m3 + \
            sin(m4 * theta) ** m5 + cos(m6 * theta) ** m7
        x = r * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
        y = r * cos(phi)
        z = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
        mlab.mesh(x, y, z, figure=self.fig)
        
    def show(self):
        return self.fig

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = Test()
        
    def show(self):
        self.t.show()

def wrapper_func(show=True):
    w = Wrapper()
    if show:
        w.show()
    return w
```

Then, in  a Jupyter Notebook cell the user write:

```
wrapper_func()
```

This should display the plot in the output cell. Unfortunately, the figure is not displayed.

Alternatively, the user can do the following:

```
w = wrapper_func(show=False)
w.show()
```

What can I do to show the figure in the output cell?

Answer (score 0):

when creating the mesh in the Test class, assign it to

```
self.surf=mlab.mesh( ... )
```

and `return self.surf in show()`

in the prgram use as:

```
t=Test();
t.show()
```

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.init_notebook()
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = mlab.figure()
        self._add_data()
        
    def _add_data(self):
        pi = np.pi
        cos = np.cos
        sin = np.sin
        dphi, dtheta = pi / 250.0, pi / 250.0
        [phi, theta] = np.mgrid[0:pi + dphi * 1.5:dphi,
                                0:2 * pi + dtheta * 1.5:dtheta]
        m0 = 4; m1 = 3; m2 = 2; m3 = 3
        m4 = 6; m5 = 2; m6 = 6; m7 = 4
        r = sin(m0 * phi) ** m1 + cos(m2 * phi) ** m3 + \
            sin(m4 * theta) ** m5 + cos(m6 * theta) ** m7
        x = r * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
        y = r * cos(phi)
        z = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
        self.surf = mlab.mesh(x, y, z, figure=self.fig)
        
    def show(self):
        return self.surf

t=Test()
t.show()
```